# I want to return some data from an async function after an async forEach loop in javascript. How can I achieve that?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, foreach, callback

I want to return some data from an async function after an async forEach loop in javascript. How can I achieve that?
I've tried this.

```js
Method 1:
async function myFunc(myArray){
    sum = 0;
    myArray.forEach(async function (element, i){
       sum += element;
    });
    return sum;
}
it returns 0 always.

Method 2:
async function myFunc(myArray){
    sum = 0;
    myArray.forEach(async function (element, i){
       sum += element;

       if(i == myArray.length-1) return sum;
    });
}
it returns 0 too.
```

Can anyone help me, please?

Comment: Why are you using async function for this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you're using async functions here, but async functions return a promise (a promise that the data will be return *at some time in the future*), so you need to use the [promise API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) to wait for that data to return. In your example there's no reason for your `forEach` callbacks to be async.

```js
const myArray = [0, 1, 2, 3];

async function myFunc(myArray) {
  let sum = 0;
  myArray.forEach(element => sum += element);
  return sum;
}

myFunc(myArray).then(console.log);
```

Comment: You can also pass `console.log` function in the `then` as `myFunc(myArray).then(console.log);`

Comment: Nice. It's like magic. I learned something new today. Cheers.